# Como limitar a quantidade de caracteres em um inputNumber?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Estou usando a extensão do Primefaces pra formatar um *input* do peso e altura de uma pessoa e não consegui. Como faço pra limitar a quantidade de caracteres digitados no *input*?

Testei com `maxlength="5"` mas não funcionou:

```jsp
<pe:inputNumber 
  id="peso" 
  maxlength="5"
  label="Peso" 
  value="#{pessoaBean.pessoaCaracFisica.peso}"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Basta usar o atributo `maxValue`.

```
    <pe:inputNumber id="peso" maxlength="5" label="Peso" 
     maxValue="200" value="#{pessoaBean.pessoaCaracFisica.peso}"/>
```

No código de exemplo acima, o maior número que ele vai permitir ser digitado é 200.